# Observe property of a custom view from Window Controller in Cocoa KVO

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

This is the hierarchy of my application, where i need to observe a property:

```
ObjectA
   |
   |-----windowControllerA (NSWindowController)
              |
              |-------Content(NSWindow)
                          |
                          |--------contentView (Custom NSView)
                                         |
                                         |---- propertyX (property to observe)
```

I try to observe from ObjectA with this code: 
`[self.windowControllerA addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"self.content.contentView.property" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:@"context"];`

But it doesn't work, i get this error :  `was sent to an object that is not KVC-compliant for the "content" property.`

What i have to do to observe propertyX from ObjectA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! this's the right path 
"window.contentView.property"

Comment: This is a pretty unusual setup. Normally propertyX would observe ObjectA.

Comment: @fakeAccount22 propertyX in my case is a NSColor. I can't understand, how can i reverse the observer ?